# Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a function defined by $g(x)= \lfloor{x+1}\rfloor$ Prove that g is onto.

Tags: functions

Let $g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ be a function defined by $g(x)= \lfloor{x+1}\rfloor$ Prove that g is onto.

The general approach I know is that its onto if for some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $g(x)=y$. Now generally I would sovle for x and just plug it back into the function but I'm unsure how that works with the floor function. I have not dealt with any problems using the floor.

Comment: Hint: consider $g$ evaluated at integers.

Comment: Please see this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/568400/prove-that-the-greatest-integer-function-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbz-is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y \in \mathbb Z$. Let $x = y-0.5 \in \mathbb R$. Then $x+1 = y+0.5$, and $g(x)=\lfloor x+1\rfloor = \lfloor y+0.5\rfloor = y$ since $y < y+0.5<y+1$, so $y$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $y+0.5$.

Hence, it follows that $g$ is onto. You can also clearly see it is not one-one.

---

Just to provide another proof : $g$ is surjective if there is a map $h$ in the opposite direction which satisfies $g \circ h = \mbox{id}$, the identity map.

Define $h : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$ by $h(z) = z-0.5$. Then, $g \circ h(z) = g(z-0.5) = z$, so $g \circ h = \mbox{id}$. Note that $g$ actually restricts to the identity on $\mathbb Z$, so even taking $h = \mbox{id}$ would have worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g_{|_\Bbb Z}: \Bbb Z \longrightarrow \Bbb Z$ such that $x\longmapsto x+1$. This is onto, so also $g$ is onto.